# How to optimize multiple subqueries to the same data set

Tags: sql, postgresql

Imagine I have a query like the following one:

```
SELECT
  u.ID,
  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      POSTS p
    WHERE
      p.USER_ID = u.ID
      AND p.TYPE = 1
  ) AS interesting_posts,
  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      POSTS p
    WHERE
      p.USER_ID = u.ID
      AND p.TYPE = 2
  ) AS boring_posts,
  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      COMMENTS c
    WHERE
      c.USER_ID = u.ID
      AND c.TYPE = 1
  ) AS interesting_comments,
  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      COMMENTS c
    WHERE
      c.USER_ID = u.ID
      AND c.TYPE = 2
  ) AS boring_comments
FROM
  USERS u;
```

( Hopefully it's correct because I just came up with it and didn't test it )

where I try to calculate the number of interesting and boring posts and comments that the user has.

Now, the problem with this query is that we have 2 sequential scans on both the `posts` and `comments` table and I wonder if there is a way to avoid that?

I could probably `LEFT JOIN` both posts and comments to the `users` table and do some aggregation but it's gonna generate a lot of rows before aggregation and I am not sure if that's a good way to go.

Comment: you could use explain to get an approximate idea of the query cost, and optimize using small changes.

Comment: Yes,try two LEFT JOINs + (conditional) aggregation.

Comment: @wildplasser I made the query a little bit more complex. My problem with left joins is that it will generate users * comments * posts rows before the aggregation which can be A LOT of rows and probably slow down the query.

Comment: There is no *before*, it is just two left joins. And outer joining posts X comments *could* be a winning strategy.

Comment: @JustMichael: No, you'd do the aggregation before joining. Please see my answer on this. Always aggregate first and join then when dealing with aggregates from multiple tables.

Comment: @wildplasser: There is a *before*. Aggregate *before* joining.

Comment: Theoretically, the  order of execution is not imposed by the order of the query. In practice, it probably is. (the query optimiser/generator might not be smart enough to know that `a LEFT b LEFT c` is equivalent to `a LEFT(b OUTER c)`)

Comment: @wildplasser: It is true that it makes no difference whether posts or comments are joined first. It does make a difference though whether you aggregate first and join the aggregates or join the mere tables instead and try to aggregate the messy intermediate result then.

Comment: Note:I am not going to investigate without the table definitions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Aggregate posts and comments and outer join them to the users table.

```
select
  u.id as user_id,
  coaleasce(p.interesting, 0) as interesting_posts,
  coaleasce(p.boring, 0)      as boring_posts,
  coaleasce(c.interesting, 0) as interesting_comments,
  coaleasce(c.boring, 0)      as boring_comments
from users u
left join
(
  select
    user_id,
    count(case when type = 1 then 1 end) as interesting,
    count(case when type = 2 then 1 end) as boring
  from posts
  group by user_id
) p on p.user_id = u.id
left join
(
  select
    user_id,
    count(case when type = 1 then 1 end) as interesting,
    count(case when type = 2 then 1 end) as boring
  from comments
  group by user_id
) c on c.user_id = u.id;
```

Answer (score 0):

compare results and execution plan (here you scan posts once):

```
with c as (
select distinct 
count(1) filter (where TYPE = 1) over (partition by USER_ID) interesting_posts
, count(1) filter (where TYPE = 2) over (partition by USER_ID) boring_posts
, USER_ID
)
, p as (select USER_ID,max(interesting_posts) interesting_posts, max(boring_posts) boring_posts from c)
SELECT
  u.ID, interesting_posts,boring_posts
  ,  ( SELECT 
      COUNT(*)
    FROM
      COMMENTS c
    WHERE
      c.USER_ID = u.ID
  ) AS comments
FROM
  USERS u
JOIN p on p.USER_ID = u.ID
```